# Where to put extra logic in django web API, in the view, or in the serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have a DRF view which extends CreateModelMixin and GenericViewSet. In the body of the post request, I want to accept an extra field, which does not belong to the related model. Then, I want to pop that extra field, use it for other purposes. I do not want to put that extra field back to the http response because it is a big and complex object. To explain it better here is a sample json input and the response that I want to return to the user:

Request:

```
# request
{
    "name": "Why Nations Fail",
    "extra_field": {
        "my_keys": ["I'm", "a", "very", "big", "array", "object.", "..."]
    }
}
```

Response:

```
# response
{
    "id": 120
    "name": "Why Nations Fail"
}
```

My problem is, I can't decide where to do this pop this extra_field; in the view or in the serializer (which extends ModelSerializer). Currently, I managed to do that by extending the `create` method handler of my view. But according the books and tutorials I've read:

> We should keep our views thin and our serializers thick.

Keeping this in mind, I have tried to pop the field in the serializer but I couldn't manage to do that, I think because I'm using ModelSerializer which gives an error when validating a non-existing model field `extra_field`.

**What I've done so far:**

Currently, I pop this extra_field by extending `create` of my view as follows:

```py
# models.py

class Book(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

```py
# serializers.py

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
# views.py

class BookViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         # notice that I'm popping the extra field instead of getting.
        extra_field = request.data.pop("extra_field")
        do_something_with_extra_field(extra_field)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(
            serializer.data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            headers=headers
        )
```

This solution exactly satisfies my needs up to now.

**I have 3 questions:**

1. Should pop `extra_field` in the view, or in the serializer? In my opinion, my serializer has nothing to do with this logic, but what happened to the "thin view, thick serializers" then?
2. If I should do that in the view, is my current implementation is right? Is it a good approach to extend view's `create` handler method?
3. If I should do that in the serializer, so how can I do it?

Comment: There's no single answer to this. If anything it depends on what `do_something_with_extra_field` is; if it's to do with creating the object, then it belongs in the serializer.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with creating the model object. It's just an extra field that is needed for other purposes.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why you're so concerned about a vague guideline. Put it where it makes sense. An extra call in the view doesn't exactly make it "thick".

Comment: How about extending ```create``` of the view. Is it a safe approach?

Comment: Look at https://sunscrapers.com/blog/where-to-put-business-logic-django/