# Automatically updating a model field when it is created

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, signals

I would like to automatically update a model field when it is created. So this is my situation. I have a custom User model that my customer can use to login. After they login, they will go to the account/profile page, which has a link to a form. Currently, when the user submits the form, it creates an instance of the `LevelTest` model(which is something I just need for the website to work). Here is the view class for the form:

```
class LevelTestView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = "leads/leveltest.html"
    form_class = LevelTestModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("profile-page")
```

and here is the LevelTestModelForm:

```
class LevelTestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LevelTest
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'age',
            'username',
        )
```

What I want to fill in automatically is the username field. In fact, I wish it doesn't even show up on the form itself when the user types in. The `username` is a field in the User Model, so I just want the new LevelTest's `username` field filled in with the current user's username. Hence, I used a post_save signal like below(which doesn't work):

```
def post_leveltest_created_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.objects.update(
            username=instance.user.username,
            description='Add Description',
            phone_number=instance.user.cellphone,
            email=instance.user.username,
        )

    
post_save.connect(post_leveltest_created_signal, sender=LevelTest)
```

I hope you guys could help me tweek the post_save signal, so that when the user creates a LevelTest instance, the LevelTest's username field(as well as the phone_number and email) is filled in with the user model's information. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you don't need to use signals, you can save username easier:

Extend `get_form_kwargs` method in your CreateView, like that:

```
 class LevelTestView:(generic.CreateView)
     ...
     def get_form_kwargs(self):
         kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
         kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
         return kwargs
```

Extend `__init__` and `save` method in your `Form`, like that:

```
class LevelTestModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
    def save(self, commit=True):
        leveltest = super().save(commit=False)
        # I think it would be better if you saved only 'user' instance
        # like this - leveltest.user = self.user (of course if you have fk to user model)
        leveltest.username = self.user.username
        leveltest.phone_number=self.user.cellphone
        leveltest.email=self.user.username
        leveltest.save()
        return leveltest
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I get this error when I submit the form: get_form_kwargs() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: did you extend init method like this - def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):???

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code. But, when I changed the kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(self), to another code I found: kwargs = super(LevelTestView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs), it worked somehow...

Comment: I also added **kwargs as a second argument to get_form_kwargs.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is okay though... Also, the cellphone field gets added to the LevelTest instance like this:('0192342342',). I hope it could just be 0192342342. Any ideas?

Comment: ohh yes it is my mistake sorry

Comment: Thanks anyways! Your answer helped a lot. Still, do you have any ideas why the cellphone field gets printed as a list?

Comment: remove come from leveltest.phone_number=self.user.cellphone, and it will fix your problem

Comment: I'm sorry "come"?

Comment: comma, "," - symbol

Answer (score 1):

I think @KIN1991's answer is pretty awesome, but you can minimize/optimize the code even more by just overriding the [`form_valid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) method. Like this:

```
class LevelTestView:(generic.CreateView)
    ...
    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
       user = self.request.user
       form.instance.username = user.username
       form.instance.phone_number=user.cellphone,
       form.instance.email=user.username
       return super().form_valid(form, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: keep logic in the view it is not good practice, view classes must be thin as it possible

Comment: Yeah. Real simple man. Thanks a lot! Exactly the "short and easy to understand" code I wanted!

Comment: @KIN1991it depends on how you want to design the coding structure. You can checkout my preferred practice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387971/2696165

Comment: its just good practice right? So, the code above doesn't have any functional issues?

Comment: No, it does not have any functional issues. :) @JohnSong

Comment: @ruddra Yes keep logic in some new layer it is good practice, but in that case it will be better to keep logic in form class because this kind of logic related with form logic. Besides Django's developers made get_form_kwargs method for using in the same cases that are described in this question. But it is just my opinion =))