# Where does business logic go in Django API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to Django. I am able to set up a basic endpoint thanks to all the tutorials but what many of them miss is Where does one put the business logic of the app? Does it just go in a random file? Do I need to connect it somehow?

File structure that I have [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeGIu.png)

I think that I should create a file in apps, then add file with any name inside that folder

Comment: There are many approaches, a lot depends on what kind of business logic are we talking about. [See the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387711/django-rest-framework-where-to-write-complex-logic-in-serializer-py-or-views-py). You can also watch videos from conferences on this topic, for eaxmple [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fqhpr_SXqzs).